# $\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}{y^{(2-a)(1-a)}\times\Big[(y-1)^{(1-a)} - y^{(1-a)}\Big]} =0, \qquad a>3$

Tags: calculus, limits

I'm working on a problem, and after some simplification, I encounter with this limit.

> $$\lim_{x \rightarrow \infty}{\Big((\log{x})^{(2-a)(1-a)}\times(\log{x} -1)^{(1-a)}\Big) - (\log{x})^{(3-a)(1-a)}} =0, \qquad a>3$$

When the term $-1$ does not exist, without taking limit, the result of $\Big((\log{x})^{(2-a)(1-a)}\times(\log{x})^{(1-a)}\Big) - (\log{x})^{(3-a)(1-a)} = 0$. But, I don't know how we can solve this problem. Can anyone prove this relation?

---

$$\log{x}=y \Rightarrow \\
\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty}{y^{(2-a)(1-a)}\times\Big[(y-1)^{(1-a)} - y^{(1-a)}\Big]} =0, \qquad a>3$$

Comment: what denotes $a$ here?

Comment: $a$ is a constant, and it is greater than $3$. For example, you can suppose $a = 10$.

Comment: The logarithm is irrelevant, you can just call $\log x$ by the name of $y$. Then you can pull out the common factor of $y^{(2-a)(1-a)}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might have been better to take out $y^{(3-a)(1-a)}$, taking you to $$\lim_{y\to \infty} y^{(3-a)(1-a)}\biggl[\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{y}\biggr)^{(1-a)} - 1 \biggr].\tag{$\ast$}$$

We know by Taylor's theorem that

$$\biggl(1 - \frac{1}{y}\biggr)^{(1-a)} = 1 + \frac{a-1}{y} + O(y^{-2}).$$

So the leading terms in the expansion of $(\ast)$ is

$$(a-1)y^{(3-a)(1-a)-1},$$

and the limiting behaviour depends on whether

$$(3-a)(1-a) - 1 = a^2 - 4a + 2 = (a-2)^2 - 2$$

is negative, zero, or positive.

For $a < 2 + \sqrt{2}$, the exponent of $y$ in the leading term is negative, so the limit will be $0$. For $a = 2 + \sqrt{2}$ the exponent is $0$, and the limit is $a-1 = 1 + \sqrt{2}$, and for $a > 2 + \sqrt{2}$ the exponent of $y$ is positive, and the limit is $+\infty$.